# Unity : Are these bugs?

Tags: unity, nautilus, shortcut-keys, online-accounts

Ubuntu Unity has some issues that I'm not sure if they should be reported as bugs or is just my fad.

1. `Run a command` (Global Shortcut `Alt + F2`) cannot find anything for `Files`, `Calculator`, `Text editor`, `Screenshot` etc. You have to type `nautilus`, `gedit` ... instead, but when you write `fire`, `firefox` pops as a result. Is this panel a search or a run command?  Because panel looks almost the same as the `Search your computer ...`  (Global shortcut `Super` key). Fells weird to lookup the same program with different keywords in a similar function panel. 
   I know that in this examples `Files` is a fancy label and `nautilus` is the actual program but the inconsistency is not appealing.
2. Any opened context menu blocks any global shortcuts. Open a context menu with right click and than press `volume down` hotkey, you have to discard first the context menu.
3. "Files/nautilus" search is striped down just to the name and the file type, what about content, date, size etc?
4. Add an online account from settings, each time `Search your computer ...` is opened you're asked to enter the password to unlock the keyring. Thats OK, but the fact that you cannot proceed with the initial task unless you enter the password is very annoying. Pressing cancel doesn't help either, it will pop out again and again for each account. The dialog also blocks any interaction with other programs opened, only the mouse pointer works.

I would like to know if you experience the same issues and if you do, do you find them annoying as well?

Some info about my installation :

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy
$ unity --version
unity 7.1.2
```

Comment: Concerning 1 & 3. alt+f2 is for running commands. It will also return results as you type from currently installed that match what you've typed. The nautilus search maintains it's own set of default columns, adjust while in search mode by r. clicking in the column name bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Run a command, it means run a command and a program name is not a command most of the time.

2.I would guess this may be a gnome or gtk issue/feature. I can use shorcuts while using context menu in Firefox and LibreOffice.

3.You can select the column view to show files details and in Nautilus preferences you can set which details to show. It is true Nautilus has been striped of many of it's features but you can also try [Nemo](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html), a Nautilus fork that keeps many of it's features.

4.Sounds like you have automatic login enabled, just disable automatic login and you should have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

IMO Unity is a bug from the outset...:P. Those are not really bugs, simply a lack of added features that have become the norm on other systems. I don't think they have the same keywords/tags or at least the universal desktop search only recognizes the actual names instead of how the desk search in the menu uses a more complete system of scanning. This allows people to both be frustrated and unity to not lock up constantly.